# how to change whole raster folder?

Tags: gdalwarp

I used to gdalwarp to reproject raster tiff file, but I did it one by one

How can I manage to do all raster in my folder (about 70 file) ? Is it possible? I am using ubuntu-64bit

Comment: How about a bash script? `for i in *.tiff; do gdalwarp {whatever options} $i  \`basename -s tiff $i\`.warped.tiff` or similar. Not really a gis question, just standard unix.

Comment: or do you want to combine the rasters and then reproject the result? in which case look at vrt's